# How to Parse CSV using runtime configurable bean class in Java

Tags: java, parsing, runtime, configurable-product

I will detailedly eplain my requirement below,.
I am going to automate a manual process. I will be reading multiple CSV files from a remote location using java.

There are five formats of input files are expected, each differs in their header structure.
For example,
Type 1 - Number, ID, Name, Phone, Address

Type 2 - Number, GID, Employee Name, Address1, Address2, Phone number

and so the other three types are also differs.

The precondition is not all the files are expected for a particular run. I need to read these files one by one, validate it, log the validation error and i have to consolidate
all the correct data from all the files together in a standard output format, in a single file
The standard output format will be like,

Number, Name, ID, Address

I need to have the above data alone in the output file and rest of the data can be ignored.

What i have tried is as follows,
I have created 5 bean classes representing each type's header. I just read an input, identify its type and parsed it. I parsed line by line.

```
public String[] parseCSV(String inputLine){
try {  
        String[] fields;

            Pattern p =
                    Pattern.compile(",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*(?![^\"]*\"))");
            fields = p.split(inputLine);
           /*for ( int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++ ) {
                System.out.println(fields[i]);
            }*/

       return fields;

    }
```

I have validated as per the validation rules and i appended each line elements into an object. I have added all the objects in to a MAP collection.
Likewise, i have created 5 beans and did the same.

But, what is the change needed now is,.
All the headers in all the five types of rosters are configurable items. hence, i have to change my bean classes everytime when the header structures are changed.

We have to create one single utility, which is configurable for all the five types of input files.
To be very clear, if type 1 input comes with 8 columns and type 3 comes with 12 columns, the utility is able to parse it.

We are going to have a table which has the data regarding the header structure of all the five types of inputs alone.
Once i read a file and identify its type, i will hit the database and read the header structure of that particular type and its column count.
I will match the column count with the input file's header count and i will have to proceed creating a bean class on runtime depending upon the header structure read now.
I will validate and consolidate as i did above.

The requirement is,
Runtime configuration of bean class, depending upon the type of input

Please let me know your idea and i will appreciate if you share the code also.

Comment: It is not adviced to use any third party libraries in this :(

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you take a look at the [Apache commons-csv library](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/).  It allows you to parse a CSV and easily get a map of the header row to get the column names.  After that, you can easily do anything you need to identify the type of CSV you have opened.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It is not advised to use any libraries heree

Comment: This sounds like the Factory pattern applies.  Create a CSVBean base class or interface.  Pass the header line from the input CSV into the factory.  In the factory, do whatever parsing, hashing or comparing you need to do to figure out which type of CSV file you are dealing with.  Return an instance of the appropriate CSVBean class.

Comment: I have already tried creating bean,. In that case, I need 5 bean class,. Later in the future if my input format changes or types of input increases, I need to do code change and rework. I need one base class which can take any format of input.